# Calculus Finding the derivative

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I have a practice problem that says:

[image: Graph]

Let $$j(x) = \frac{g(x)}{f(x)}$$

Find $j'(1)$:

I don't know how to do this. The answer the book has is $-2$. What I tried to do was set $j(0) = \frac{g(0)}{f(0)}= 0$ because the derivative of a constant (such as $1$) is $0$.

Can someone explain what I have to do?

Comment: what else is given?

Comment: Quotient rule? $\space$

Comment: I forgot the graph, I apologize. I'll upload it in a few seconds.

Comment: The answer depends on $f$ and $g$. You want to know the rule for $(g/f)'$.

Comment: Also, $j(0) = 0$ doesn't imply $j'(0) = 0$, since $j$ is not constant.

Comment: I added the graph.

Comment: Well now you can clearly see what $f$ and $g$ are, it shouldn't be that hard to apply the quotient rule and evaluate at $x = 1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$j'(x)=\frac{f(x)g'(x)-g(x)f'(x)}{f^{2}(x)}$$
So $$j'(1)=\frac{f(1)g'(1)-g(1)f'(1)}{f^{2}(1)}=\frac{2\times (-1)-3\times 2}{4}=-2$$

Answer (score 0):

Given the graph, we can write that for $0 \lt x \leq 2$, we have : $$f(x) = 2x$$$$g(x) = 4-x$$
Hence (since we exclude $x=0$) : $$j(x) = \frac{4-x}{2x} = \frac{2}{x} - \frac{1}{2}$$ 
Now, for $0 \lt x \leq 2$, $j$ is continuous, so you can derivate the expression and you have : $$j'(x) = -\frac{2}{x^2}$$

And finally, $$j'(1) = -\frac{2}{1} = -2$$